# Azure web app timezone error in asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, timezone, azure-webapps

I have web app in azure paas environment. I need to convert the time in different timezone, i have following code which run perfectly fine on dev machine but when i deploy on azure paas environment it throw error

```
TimeZoneInfo serverTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);
                return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(_lastUpdatedDate.Value, serverTimeZoneInfo);
```

First line throw exception. Error getting value from 'DateCreated' on 'ViewModels.Orders.OrderActivityViewModel'

Comment: Can you include the line that is throwing the error? I don't see any reference to the DateCreated property in the code you posted.

Comment: You should copy the exception verbatim. It's not occurring on the first line you've pasted here.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Don't use the `TimeZone` class.  It is obsolete.  Use only the `TimeZoneInfo` class.
- The `StandardName` is NOT the same as the `Id` for all cases.  It is also impacted by OS language, where the `Id` is not.
- The local time zone's Id is at `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`, though there's no point in finding it by Id when you already have it.  You'd just use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.
- If you're just converting local time to UTC, you don't need to mess with time zones at all, just use `.ToUniversalTime()` on your original `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` value.
- The server's time zone probably already is UTC.  That is the default in Azure anyway.  Thus it isn't going to do anything at all.
- If necessary, you can change Azure App Service's `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting (on Windows only), but I don't recommend that.  If you have a specific time zone in mind, then you would pass that ID into `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`.
- As others pointed out, the error you reported isn't in the code you gave, so likely none of this is going to help you.